# enumeration in enumeration

Tags: enumerate, itemize

Using the hints in this post: [Defining a command that accepts multiple but non-determined in total number of parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133497/defining-a-command-that-accepts-multiple-but-non-determined-in-total-number-of-p), I have a new description defined.

The issue is that when I add enumeration inside of it, I have first pointer(dot) in the wrong position. How can I move the dot to the next line?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\newcommand{\myitem}[2]{%
  \item #1
  \begin{description}
  #2
  \end{description}
}
\newcommand{\II}[2]{%
  \item[#1] #2
}

\chapterstyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\myitem{Scenario average temperature}{
  \II{Description:}{In this scenario, application developers use to share average
temperature for 100 nodes.  }
  \II{Sequence of functions:}{}
  \II{Environments needed to execute the scenario:}{}
  \II{What triggers the execution and what determines the completion:}{
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
}
}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that the first bullet of nested lists is inlined into the outer list item is a deliberate feature of the latex list implementation. I can't say it's a feature I have ever wanted but still...

```
\newcommand{\II}[2]{%
  \item[#1]\mbox{}\ignorespaces #2
}
```

Is one simple way to avoid it however the  `What triggers the execution and what determines the completion:}` text in your example is wider than the page so the layout is still less than ideal, perhaps you need a list layout that allows the item to linebreak?